# Using the trace class in new thread crashes IIS7 in vb.net/asp.net web app

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, trace

This is about using Trace in multi threaded web app

I am attempting to use tracing in a new thread started with

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf WorkMethod, autoEvent)

My code works without crashing until I add

Trace.warn(message,category)

to a function called within the new thread

The error is below, the crash usually stops the application pool, so the page fails to load and the error message must be extracted from the IIS event log

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 2576
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> StackTrace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Trace()